# how to remove the warning "This will upload all files from [Folder]. Only do this if you trust this site."

Tags: javascript, c#, html

While uploading the folder using Webkitdirectory html feature, we come across the warning message that says "This will upload all files from [Folder]. Only do this if you trust this site."

I want to remove this warning.

```
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple />
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? This seems to be a security feature of the browser; it makes sure that a malicious website can't snaffle all your files. As such you probably can't disable it.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. Firefox it works perfectly but in Chrome it shows the alert.

Comment: Is it atleast possible to alter the message? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately there is no way to fix it because there is a new security policy:**

previously you could socially engineer a user into holding enter and it uploaded their whole home folder to the attacker site.

There is no way of skipping this step.